# How to best compare these two strings for values even though they are in random order?

Tags: php, sql, database-design, querying

I have a string in my database that is four characters long, such as `A487`. The user can search that database by typing in four characters. I am having a hard time conceptualizing how to implement this elegantly because of these factors:

1. The user's input can be in any order. For example, the user may type in `2345` and this would need to match the database entry for `5432`.
2. The input needs to account for pairs of numbers. For example, one entry may be `2245`. If the user enters `4252`, it needs to find this entry.

In short, I need the search to return all results where there is an exact character for character match regardless of the order of the characters themselves. Any thoughts?

**Solution:**

I decided to go with the method of creating a sorted column on import so that I could then sort the user's input using the same method and compare exact strings. To do this:

I used PHP's natural sorting algorithm (it doesn't matter how you actually sort these, as long as it's consistent among both the database value and user input).

```
$hand = "AT77";    

// Create an array with each card in it.
$cards = [$hand[0], $hand[1], $hand[2], $hand[3]];

// Sort the array using natural sort algorithim
natsort($cards);

// Create a string out of array
$sortedHand = implode($cards);
```

I insert this value in the database under hand_sorted, and then I can simply use the same `natsort` on an array with the user's input to compare for exact strings. There was no discernible damage in terms of import time for my exact project, where the user is uploading CSVs between 40k and 100k rows long. Ended up being the pefect solution.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone is it possible to alphabetise the letters in the table column ASC (re-order each string in the column), and alphabetise the input string and seek exact matches?  I wonder what Bill Karwin would do.

Comment: @mickmackusa Wow, that is a very interesting idea. It does appear to me that this would work upon first thought.

Comment: I've never tried anything like that.  I don't know how I would code that up.  I've requested Bill's attention -- who is wicked clever.  If it can be done, he will know.

Comment: Would you be open to adding an extra column to your database?  Just save a "sorted string" column and use that for querying.   Maybe I'll write an answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa I mean, it will definitely work. I can't imagine there is any way to do this without modifying the values in PHP either on import or on lookup, and performance is a big factor, so I will see how this does and report back. The hit should probably be taken on import, with the average import being about 100,000 rows (from a CSV file). Not sure how big the impact will be.

Comment: Yes.  There will be a hit somewhere, but it is wise to get stung once and never again, versus having to use heavy `REGEXP` / `LIKE` / `IN` queries each time.

Comment: I am curious.  What is the card game?

Comment: Please do not [edit] your question to include your resolving approach -- that is what answers are for. You don't need natural sorting on single charactering sorting. You script can be written (a little less clearly) as a one-liner. [`echo implode((function($cards) { sort($cards); return $cards; })(str_split($hand)));`](https://3v4l.org/tJMWB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow for simple querying, I'll recommend that you add a new column to your database table that stores your 4-char strings with each letter occurring alphabetically.  Then you can simply alphabetize your input string and seek exact matches.  This should be highly efficient.

```
----------------------------------
col1 | unsorted  | sorted | col2 |
----------------------------------
blah | 3542      | 2345   | blah |
blah | 4533      | 3345   | blah |
blah | 4253      | 2345   | blah |
----------------------------------
```

This keeps your data true and also allows for easy querying.  You only need to query on the `sorted` column values.

Answer (score 0):

Your application should perform a query matching against every permutation.

For a 4-character string this will be 24 options. (4! = 4*3*2*1 = 24)

Assuming you’re using SQL, it would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column IN ('4252', '4525', ...)
```

Comment: Yes, this was my initial determination. I determined there must be a more elegant way to do it, but perhaps the only room for elegance is in how I generate the list of permutations. Any recommendations on how you would do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you vaguely specified that this string will be alphanumeric, it should be an easy concept to program once grasped.

The most logically simple method I can recommend is to simply set each character as its own variable, then iterate through your database and check each entry, saying "*does this database entry contain every character once*?" If each character variable is present in the entry, then you've found your match.

Let's say you have a user's input of `2235` to search for, and your program assigned each to the following:

```
int num1 = 2;
int num2 = 2;
int num3 = 3;
int num4 = 5;
```

You could iterate through the database, and if it were to come across `2235`, it should be able to say "is the first integer in this entry equal to num1?" If not, then it can compare the first integer to num2, and so on. If there is no match, this implies that the database entry contains none of what the user input, so you can move on. If it does match, then you can move on and say "does the second integer in this entry match num1?" And so on. This should make it satisfy your first requirement of finding a match in any order.

The flaw in that logic would be that a test case such as `2225` would pass, because the first three integers would match num1. To get around this, you could use booleans or other if statements to say "if num1 matched any of the integers of the database entry, stop comparing it with the other integers." That way, all num variables should match up with one of the characters in the entry, to find a complete match in any order.

Alternatively, you could fill an Array or other Data Structure with the user's search inquiry and perform a similar process. Either should give you a similar result.

Comment: The only problem I see with this is that you said "does this database entry contain every character once?" The problem is, if the user specifies that the entry is `2235`, then I need it to check if the `2` is there twice. But if I break each character up into a single variable, it will just check two times to see if `2` is there once. That means that searching `2235` could return something like `2356`.

Comment: @Ben86 I've edited my post to clarify this, give it a read and see if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well, when permutations are involved it can get really expensive. Maybe a two step approach is an option. First filter by a rather coarse but quick method and then filter the fewer results with the exact but more expensive method.

E.g. compute a scalar value for such a string which is equal if the strings are equal. Just as a quick shot, there might be better methods, add the ASCII values of each character. You could materialize that in the database table, use a trigger for example. Possibly index it. Then query the table against this value and you'll have a subset of possible candidates. Filter that subset by an exact comparison then. It will at least reduce the search space on which you'll have to apply the more expensive exact method.

For an ad hoc solution that does not need any schema changes (but doesn't allow indexes for optimization), you could also split the user input into the individual characters, lets name them `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. You could then do a query like

```
SELECT *
       FROM your_table
       WHERE substring(your_column, 1, 1) IN (a, b, c, d)
             AND substring(your_column, 2, 1) IN (a, b, c, d)
             AND substring(your_column, 3, 1) IN (a, b, c, d)
             AND substring(your_column, 4, 1) IN (a, b, c, d);
```

and the continue like above by further examining that result with the exact method.

Just an idea...

Comment: I'm not sure this will do the job.  I mean, it doesn't require that each char occurs just once, right?  See my comment on Sunny's answer about `2223` and `2233` and `2333`

Comment: Alone it won't do the job. You'd have to then find the exact matches in the subset of this first step. But anyway, mickmackusa is right, haven't seen that before i posted. Use his solution and just sort both strings by character and compare them. That should be the most efficient thing here, given that sort complexity can be as low as O(n log n).

Comment: As often as I read those Big O expressions on this site, I should really get around to learning what all of that stuff means.  ...one day.  According to the OP's comment under the question, we are dealing with hundreds of thousands of rows, likely millions.  So efficiency is definitely going to count on this task.

Comment: @mickmackusa: You might also just correct me if I'm wrong. I don't think I don't make mistakes or misunderstand some stuff. ;) (And by the way I upvoted your answer as I think you're right and your approach is by far the best. Just to clarify, if my previous comment has been misleading regarding that.)

Comment: I make mistakes too.  I'm just talking this out, because I've never considered a challenge like this.  An interesting question.

Comment: @mickmackusa: Yeah, my first comment was really misleading. It was meant to address the OP and tell him that I back your approach. Only the first part was a reply to yours -- mine might work but is by far less performant and less elegant. Sorry for that.